# Is there an existing Predicate representing the instanceof operator?

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java 8's lambda expression to partition a list (using `.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(...))`) and I need my partition criteria to be whether the element is an instance of a given class.

Doing as follows works

```java
list.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(elt -> elt instanceof EltType))
```

But is there an existing "`InstanceOf`" predicate that I can use via method reference instead?

Comment: `EltType.class::isInstance`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you can use [`Class::isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof`
>   operator

Example

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(EltType.class::isInstance))
```

Comment: Did the OP ask how to implement their logic with a method reference? I must have missed that.

Comment: @Eran I suppose this is the most idiomatic way to implement an "instanceof predicate" in functional java - feel free to provide a more concise example...

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for, thanks @Michael !

Comment: @GyroGearless I didn't claim to have a better answer. I just didn't understand what "InstanceOf predicate" means.

Comment: I indeed had some trouble wording it haha

Comment: @GyroGearless "concise" and "idiomatic" are not the same. Neither, `elt -> elt instanceof EltType` nor `EltType.class::isInstance`, are more idiomatic than the other.  When you rename `elt` to `e`, you can't even say that either is more concise than the other. By the way, `e -> e instanceof EltType` is a stateless lambda which will end up as a singleton whereas `EltType.class::isInstance` will capture the `Class` object, so, as contradicting intuition as it might be, the method reference may be less efficient, though, that's a tiny difference in practice.